# Double filter not working in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some issue in filtering JSON array. Here is code and results that I want, So please help me to filter this.

```
var all = [
  {
    data : "test1",
    dataArray : [
      {
        name : "abc",
        status : true,
        address: "test"
      }, {
        name : "xyz",
        status : false,
        address: "test"
      }, {
        name : "pqr",
        status : true,
        address: "test"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    data : "test2",
    dataArray : [
      {
        name : "abc",
        status : true,
        address: "test"
      }, {
        name : "xyz",
        status : false,
        address: "test"
      }, {
        name : "pqr",
        status : false,
        address: "test"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    data : "test3",
    dataArray : [
      {
        name : "abc",
        status : false,
      }, {
        name : "xyz",
        status : false,
      }, {
        name : "pqr",
        status : true,
      },
    ]
  }
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(all.filter((a)=>a.dataArray.filter((b)=>b.status==true)),null,2));
```

want result like this : 
only data with status true but I don't know why filter return all the JSON data. Is there any issue with nested filter??

```
a = [
    {
      data : "test1",
      dataArray : [
        {
          status : true,
          address: "test"
        },{
          status : true,
          address: "test"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      data : "test2",
      dataArray : [
        {
          status : true,
          address: "test"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      data : "test3",
      dataArray : [
        {
            status : true,
            address: "test"
        }, {
            status : true,
            address: "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I used nested filter but it is not worked. How can I get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `filter` to `dataArray`, not `all`

```
all.forEach( s => s.dataArray = s.dataArray.filter( t => t.status ) )
```

**Note**

- This solution mutates `all` array, so in case you don't want to mutate - create a deep copy of `all` first.

**Demo**

```js
var all = [{
    data: "test1",
    dataArray: [{
      name: "abc",
      status: true,
      address: "test"
    }, {
      name: "xyz",
      status: false,
      address: "test"
    }, {
      name: "pqr",
      status: true,
      address: "test"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    data: "test2",
    dataArray: [{
      name: "abc",
      status: true,
      address: "test"
    }, {
      name: "xyz",
      status: false,
      address: "test"
    }, {
      name: "pqr",
      status: false,
      address: "test"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    data: "test3",
    dataArray: [{
      name: "abc",
      status: false,
    }, {
      name: "xyz",
      status: false,
    }, {
      name: "pqr",
      status: true,
    }, ]
  }
];

all.forEach(s => s.dataArray = s.dataArray.filter(t => t.status))

console.log(all);
```